# Docker for Windows NAT network sharing doesn't work

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I am trying to start two docker containers (docker EE 17.06) that share the same NAT network on windows Server 1709. I start my first container with:

```
docker run -it --net=nat --name=container1 microsoft/nanoserver:1709
```

And in another window the second container:

```
docker run -it --net=container:container1 microsoft/nanoserver:1709
```

Now the first container works perfectly, ipconfig looks good, but in the second container ipconfig does not see the DNS servers and I can't ping anything.

I also tried to run it as:

```
docker run -it --net=container:container1 --ipc=container:container1 --pid=container:container1 microsoft/nanoserver:709
```

I tried to do the same on Ubuntu, with bridge network and alpine images and it worked, but for windows I can't figure it out.